# vb net method in controller not call in second call

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have a web application in vb net MVC and I am having a problem.
My page displays the stock of an article with an url: Stock? Id = ART01

When I go to my page once, the method is called in the controller (I put a breakpoint)
If I refresh the page, the method is not called in the controller why?

I tried to add this thinking it was a cache issue:

```
<AttributeUsage((AttributeTargets.Class Or AttributeTargets.Method))> _
Public NotInheritable Class NoCacheAttribute
    Inherits ActionFilterAttribute

    Public Overrides Sub OnResultExecuting(ByVal filterContext As ResultExecutingContext)
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1))
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(False)
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches)
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore()
        MyBase.OnResultExecuting(filterContext)
    End Sub
End Class

<NoCacheAttribute>
Public Class MyController
    Inherits Controller
```

But it doesn't work.

Do you have an idea ?